# 301 redirect and rewrite .htacess for index page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite and redirect dynamic url to make user-friendly urls. But something broke with index page.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /?theme=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /%1? [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /?theme=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**?** is a special character in regex so you need to escape it using a backslash in the RewriteCond's pattern

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /\?theme=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /%1? [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /?theme=$1 [QSA,L]
```